# Highslide: Opening a webpage instead of expanding an image

Tags: javascript, highslide

Is there any way to simply open a web page when an image in the gallery is clicked instead of expanding the image on the page? I'm sure that the solution - if there is one - would probably require changing the following code:

```
onclick="return hs.expand(this, inPageOptions )
```

Comment: Do you simple want to open the page by giving URL?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes, that's all want to do. I've searched and searched but haven't found anything.

Comment: Are you using a regular Highslide in-page gallery like this: http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-in-page.html?

Comment: @RoadRash Yes. That's pretty much the example I used.

Answer (score 1):

See this demo gallery: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/KtDpz/

Use [hs.Expander.prototype.custom](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.custom) to set the URL you want to open when clicking each image in the gallery:

```
onclick="return hs.expand(this, inPageOptions, {url: 'http://roadrash.no/'})"
```

Replace the `hs.Expander.prototype.onImageClick` code with this:

```
// go to url when clicking the image
hs.Expander.prototype.onImageClick = function() {
    if (this.custom) {
        window.open(this.custom.url);
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but try

```
onclick = "window.open('http://www.yoururl.com')";
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It was one of the first things I tried. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post entire code block where `onclick` is used? Also - does it throw an error or simple nothing happens?

Comment: The code sample is long. But it would be exactly like the in-page gallery on http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-in-page.html. It doesn't give an actual error. It simply doesn't show the image at all.

Comment: I tried that replace in that example (did a replace in dev-tools directly in the source) and it seems to work

Comment: Hmm... I'm going to strip out some other stuff I added and try it that way. Thank you.